Font sizes for public screens
I'm working on similar public screen as on airport for schedule, is there any reasearch done about font sizes which ones are best for full hd screens ?


It all depends on distance. This link points to an older question but might be interesting: https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/27229/how-do-i-figure-out-the-right-size-font-text-for-a-given-read-distance

you need to look into signage design. Text size is defined mainly by distance from the viewer, not screen resolution.
